# Python sortedcontainers is too slow

Tags: python, conda, sortedlist, sortedcontainers

#This is my code

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList, SortedSet, SortedDict
import timeit
import random


def test_speed1(data):
    SortedList(data)

def test_speed2(data):
    sorted_data = SortedList()
    for val in data:
        sorted_data.add(val)


data = []
numpts = 10 ** 5
for i in range(numpts):
    data.append(random.random())
print(f'Num of pts:{len(data)}')

sorted_data = SortedList()
n_runs=10
result = timeit.timeit(stmt='test_speed1(data)', globals=globals(), number=n_runs)
print(f'Speed1 is {1000*result/n_runs:0.0f}ms')

n_runs=10
result = timeit.timeit(stmt='test_speed2(data)', globals=globals(), number=n_runs)
print(f'Speed2 is {1000*result/n_runs:0.0f}ms')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvyp2.png)

The code for test speed2 is supposed to take 12~ ms (I checked the setup they report). Why does it take 123 ms (10X slowers)???
test_speed1 runs in 15 ms (which makes sense)

I am running in Conda.
The
This is where they outlined the performance
https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html

Comment: What do you mean "supposed to take 12~ ms". According to whom? The graph is the result of *some* code; it's not necessarily the code you show above. You should run a similar test with other data structures and see how each behaves with  *your* test, rather than trying to compare your test one data structure to some unknown test.

Comment: Where exactly are you looking to see "12~ ms"? For adding 10⁵ values, the plot rather looks like 2 ms to me.

Comment: I might have a better answer, but I'd really need to know where you're looking.

Comment: I want to add data to a sorted list. Data comes in as a stream. I want something efficient as the list is big

Comment: Is that just a random thought or are you trying to respond to something we said?

Comment: Oh. No. It is actually what I am trying to do. Insert streaming data efficiently.

Comment: So you're just ignoring the question?

Answer (score 2):

You are presumably not executing your benchmark in the same conditions as they do:

- you are not using the same benchmark code,
- you don't use the same computer with the same performance characteristics,
- you are not using the same Python version and environment,
- you are not running the same OS,
- etc.

Hence, the benchmark results are not comparable and you cannot conclude anything about the performance (and certainly not that "sortedcontainers is too slow").

Performance is only relative to a given execution context and they only stated that their solution is faster **relative** to other concurrent solutions.

If you really wish to execute the benchmark on your computer, follow the [instructions](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) they give in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like you overlooked the bug visible in their code: They repeatedly add 10^5 values to the same list instead of to a new one each time. (But I don't think it makes a big difference.)

Comment: Hmm, at least I *think* they're trying to measure 10⁵ adds, not 10⁶, as they're dividing the time by n_runs. But as I just commented, the graph looks like 2 ms to me for that. And in that case, they'd be 60 times slower, which is so much that I actually find it suspicious and doubt whether all our reasons combined can explain it...

Comment: I did check the machines and as you can see, I can get 15 ms if I add the entire list in one run vs 115 if I add them one at a time

Answer (score 0):

"init() uses Python’s highly optimized sorted() function while add() cannot.". This is why the speed2 is faster than the speed3.

This is the answer I got from the developers on the sortedcontainers library.

Comment: There is no speed3. And their benchmark isn't using the constructor like that, it uses add. So this doesn't explain why *your* adds seem to be much slower.